# Calculating estimates in SPSS Amos

Tags: spss

I recently encountered a problem when calculating estimates, I got the message that say one of my variables is represented in a rectangle yet it's not an observered variable , how do I overcome this challenge?

I was trying to calculate the estimates after drawing the path diagram

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.